# Grails Spring Security Core Plugin and mongoDB GORM Plugin

Tags: mongodb, spring-security, grails-orm, grails-2.0

Anyone knows if Spring Security Core Plugin is compatible with mongoDB GORM Plugin ? I have three domain classes "User, Role, and UserRole", I added static mapWith ='mongo' to "'User, and Role" in order to make Spring Security Core Plugin read from mongoDB rather than Hibernate/MySQL but I get the following Exception, I know that Spring Security Core Plugin is trying to use Hibernate to join and map data across these tables, I wanna know if I can intercept that and make it redirect to MongoDB Rather than Hibernate :

|Running Grails application 
Configuring Spring Security Core ... 
... finished configuring Spring Security Core

```
Error | 
2013-11-30 13:22:56,976 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table user_role refers to an unmapped class: com.myProject.Role 
Message: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table user_role refers to an unmapped class: com.myProject.Role 
    Line | Method 
->>  104 | postProcessBeanFactory in org.grails.datastore.gorm.plugin.support.PersistenceContextInterceptorAggregator 
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    262 | run                    in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask 
|   1145 | runWorker . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor 
|    615 | run                    in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker 
^    744 | run . . . . . . . . .  in java.lang.Thread 
Caused by MappingException: An association from the table user_role refers to an unmapped class: com.myProject.Role 
->>  104 | postProcessBeanFactory in org.grails.datastore.gorm.plugin.support.PersistenceContextInterceptorAggregator 
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    262 | run                    in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask 
|   1145 | runWorker . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor 
|    615 | run                    in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker 
^    744 | run . . . . . . . . .  in java.lang.Thread 
Error | 
Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

Comment: Any reason you haven't also setup mapping on your UserRole class?

Comment: I would like to do the same with CouchDB

Comment: have you seen the plugin for it in Grails plugin page ?